# Output timed audio from 2 looped arrays [Javascript]

Tags: javascript, for-loop, audio, settimeout

I have two arrays, array A and array B. There are an equal amount of values inside of each array, but the arrays change length, having a maximum length of 6. What I'm trying to achieve is to play two sounds, one from array A and one from B one after another, 1-6 times, depending on the array length. Like this:

- Play sound 1 from array 1.
- wait a second
- Play sound 1 from array 2.
- wait two seconds.
- (repeat)
- Play sound 2 from array 1.
- wait a second
- Play sound 2 from array 2.
- wait two seconds.
   (and so on...)

Attempt 1

```
for (var i=0; i<=numberOfValues-1; i++){
    setTimeout(function(){playSoundArray1[i];},1000);
    setTimeout(function(){playSoundArray2[i];},2000);
}
```

Attempt 2

```
function externalTimeout(i, array, time){
    setTimeout(function(){array[i];},time);
}

for (let i=0; i<=numberOfValues-1; i++){
    externalTimeout(i,playSoundArray1,1000);
    externalTimeout(i,playSoundArray2,2000);
}
```

Attempt two partially works, it plays all the sounds from the first array "together", and then plays all the sounds from the second array "together". 
I do understand why these don't work, but I cannot come up with a solution. Suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
     var a   = [1,2,3];
      var b   = [4,5,6];
      var i   = 0;
      update();
      
      function update(){
      
            if(i===a.length){
                  console.log('complete');
                  return;
            }
            
            playa(i);
            
            i++;
            
      }//update
            
      
      function playa(i){
            
            console.log(a[i]);
            setTimeout(playb,1000,i);
            
      }//playa
      
      function playb(i){
      
            console.log(b[i]);
            setTimeout(update,2000);
            
      }//playb
```